# How to install MariaDB in Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, mariadb

I am new to Linux and VirtualBox, however I have set up a guest Fedora 19 machine (32 bit because I don't have VT-x capabilities) via VirtualBox on Windows 7 and am wanting to install MariaDB.  I am also new to MariaDB but can complete basic operations in MySQL command line.

The most authoritative looking posts I can find on getting this set up are:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ReplaceMySQLwithMariaDB
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_Installing_MariaDB_in_f19

However they seem to have slightly different instructions and the 'Setting up MariaDB Repositories' feature here:

https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/

does not seem to include an option for selecting Fedora 19.

So my question is what are the exact steps required to install MariaDB in Fedora 19?

I am new to terminology like keys, checksums and repo's so it would be great if steps could be shown in a dot point list.

**Edit:** There is also an article at the link below that almost gets me over the comprehension line but I would appreciate confirmation and clarification of the steps:

http://www.bytebot.net/blog/archives/2013/04/30/testing-fedora-19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for the matching MySQL version.  This means that anywhere a MySQL database is required, a MariaDB database can be provided without changing anything in the requiring packages.

Due to the buyout of Sun by Oracle, and Oracle having a history of closing the source on many projects, the Fedora Team opted to replace MySQL with MariaDB in Fedora 19.  Due to the fact that MariaDB is a drop-in replacement, they opted to do this by re-directing the YUM package manager to automatically replace references for MySQL with references to MariaDB, and provide the MySQL package as community-MySQL.

In essence, this means that issuing the command `# yum install mysql-server` result in mariadb-server mariadb-libs and mariadb installing.

This process installs MariaDB 5.5.30 to mirror MySQL 5.5.  If you are trying to get MariaDB 10 (still in development), you can safely build the package from source.

Comment: Could you please direct me to a place where I could gain a thorough understanding of what 'build the package from source' means and how to do it?

Comment: The first 2 links in your post are depreciated (they refer to tests that were being performed to verify the replacement process before the Fedora 19 release).

Comment: Here are the instructions for the installation for 10.0.3 Alpha https://kb.askmonty.org/en/installing-mariadb-binary-tarballs/.  You may need to run `# yum install bzr gzip tar gcc gcc-c++ make libtool bison ncurses-devel zlib-devel automake autoconf cmake` to install pre-requisites (not mentioned in the mariadb documentation)

Comment: actually that link is for the binary packages (pre-compiled).  For the source package, https://kb.askmonty.org/en/generic-build-instructions/ is more detailed.

Answer (score 6):

You can find MariaDB in Fedora 18+ repository and it will be included in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.
To install it we have to erase some old stuff.
If MySQL is installed we have to delete with yum. Perform a backup with mysqldump (be paranoid :-) ).

```
# mysqldump --all-databases > `hostname`.`date +%Y%m%d`.bkp.sqldump 
# yum  remove mysql mysql-libs mysql-devel mysql-server
```

After that we can install MariaDB, with yum, of course:

```
# yum install mariadb mariadb-libs mariadb-devel mariadb-server
```

Start and enable at boot
Now we can start it. We have also to enable at boot. If we have to reboot the server, evrythink shoud start with no further operations.

```
# systemctl start mysqld
# systemctl enable mysqld
```

No, this isn’t a typo, MariaDB service is called mysqld. :-)

you can find an useful howto on this page:

http://www.extraordy.com/fedora-19-how-to-install-mariadb/

Kind regards,
Gaetano

Comment: You should put a summary of the content of that link. The link might be unusable in future.

Comment: With Fedora 20 /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service is a symlink to mariadb.service and `systemctl enable mysqld` fails, but `systemctl enable mariadb` works as expected.